# What is the preferred production setup for eve

Tags: eve

I am setting up an Eve instance for production and wonder what is the "preferred production setup" for Eve - if there is such a thing. 
uWSGI seem to work nice.
Gunicorn works nice with standard Flask - but not so easily for Eve as Eve has an implicit import of "settings.py".
Suggestions or recommandations?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/) is pretty popular with Eve and Flask in general. Because it is non-blocking and uses epoll, it can handle thousands of simultaneous standing connections, which means it is ideal for real-time web services. Integrating this service with Flask is straightforward ([source](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/deploying/wsgi-standalone/#tornado)).

So imagine you have your average `run.py` script for launching your REST API:

```
from eve import Eve
app = Eve()

# custom stuff here

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

You could then have a `run-production.py` script like this:

```
from tornado.wsgi import WSGIContainer
from tornado.httpserver import HTTPServer
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop

from run import app

http_server = HTTPServer(WSGIContainer(app))
http_server.listen(5000)
IOLoop.instance().start()
```

You can then launch `run.py` when debugging, and `run-production.py` when going live.

Comment: You are welcome. Please accept the answer if you found that it was the correct solution (and eventually vote it up).